# Is there a way to reference setVisible() and dispose() from an ActionListener in a separate class file?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I'm working on a very complicated, multi-layered Swing GUI, and the main issue I'm running into right now involves having a JButton ActionListener perform setVisible() on a separate JFrame and immediately dispose() of the current JFrame. Because of the length of my code, it's important that main, both JFrames, and the ActionListener are all split into individual class files. I wrote a VERY simplified version of my problem, split into 4 tiny class files. Here they are:

File 1:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Test {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      
      JFrame g1 = new GUI1();
      g1.pack();
      g1.setLocation(200,200);
      g1.setVisible(true);
      
      JFrame g2 = new GUI2();
      g2.pack();
      g2.setLocation(400,200);
      g2.setVisible(false);
      
   }
}
```

File 2:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class GUI1 extends JFrame {

   JPanel panel;
   JButton button;
   
   public GUI1() {
      
      super("GUI1");
      setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      
      panel = new JPanel();
      button = new JButton("Create GUI2");
      button.addActionListener(new Listener());
      
      add(panel);
      add(button);
      
   }
}
```

File 3:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class GUI2 extends JFrame {

   JPanel panel;
   JLabel label;
   
   public GUI2() {
            
      super("GUI2");
      setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      
      panel = new JPanel();
      label = new JLabel("I'm alive!");
      
      add(panel);
      add(label);
      
   }
}
```

File 4:

```
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Listener implements ActionListener {
   
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
   
      GUI2.setVisible(true);
      GUI1.dispose();
   
   }
}
```

As you can see, the only function of the ActionListener is to set GUI2 to visible and dispose of GUI1, but it runs the error "non-static method (setVisible(boolean) and dispose()) cannot be referenced from a static context". I figure this is because both methods are trying to reference objects that were created in main, which is static. My confusion is how to get around this, WITHOUT combining everything into one class.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

EDIT:
Here's the above code compiled into one file... although it returns the exact same error.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Test {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      
      JFrame g1 = new GUI1();
      g1.pack();
      g1.setLocation(200,200);
      g1.setVisible(true);
      
      JFrame g2 = new GUI2();
      g2.pack();
      g2.setLocation(400,200);
      g2.setVisible(false);
      
   }
}

class GUI1 extends JFrame {

   JPanel panel;
   JButton button;
   
   public GUI1() {
      
      super("GUI1");
      setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      
      panel = new JPanel();
      button = new JButton("Create GUI2");
      button.addActionListener(new Listener());
      
      add(panel);
      add(button);
      
   }
}

class GUI2 extends JFrame {

   JPanel panel;
   JLabel label;
   
   public GUI2() {
            
      super("GUI2");
      setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      
      panel = new JPanel();
      label = new JLabel("I'm alive!");
      
      add(panel);
      add(label);
      
   }
}

class Listener implements ActionListener {
   
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
   
      GUI2.setVisible(true);
      GUI1.dispose();
   
   }
}
```

Comment: *"a separate JFrame"* 1) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) 2) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). * See note. 3) More specifically though.. *"perform setVisible() on a separate JFrame and immediately dispose() of the current JFrame."* Use a [`CardLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5786005/418556).

Comment: * Note: The problem here is **not** the amount of code, but that there are 4 **`public`** classes. Leave the one with `main(String[])` method as public, demote the other classes to default access (i.e. remove the `public` specifier) and paste them in after the main class to enable a single copy/paste in order to see it work (or fail).

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass instances of frame1 and frame2 to your `ActionListener`.

```
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Listener implements ActionListener {

   private JFrame frame1, frame2;

   public Listener(JFrame frame1, JFrame frame2) {
       this.frame1 = frame1;
       this.frame2 = frame2;
   }
   
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      frame2.setVisible(true);
      frame1.dispose();
   }

}
```

This means you have to pass an instance of frame2 to your `GUI1` class.

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class GUI1 extends JFrame {

   JPanel panel;
   JButton button;
   
   public GUI1(JFrame frame2) {
      
      super("GUI1");
      setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      
      panel = new JPanel();
      button = new JButton("Create GUI2");
      button.addActionListener(new Listener(this, frame2));
      
      add(panel);
      add(button);
   }

}
```

This means you have to create the frames in the reverse order.

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Test {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      
      JFrame g2 = new GUI2();
      g2.pack();
      g2.setLocation(400,200);
      g2.setVisible(false);

      JFrame g1 = new GUI1(g2);
      g1.pack();
      g1.setLocation(200,200);
      g1.setVisible(true);  
   }

}
```

Comment: THANK YOU Gilbert!!! This is EXACTLY what I needed!!!